# Restore the previous saved status into redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

We're using redux and immutable objects on our redux store.

The scenario is that a user might dump the current store status into database and later the user might be able to restore it.

I'm a newbie to redux.

Is there any keywords to search for this kind of techniques?

We will try to dump the status into JSON format and reload it from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word is "persistence".  There's [dozens of existing libraries for persisting Redux state](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/store-persistence.md) already - you can either try using them as-is, or look at how they work and implement some of the approaches yourself.

To actually persist the state, you'd normally either do it in a store subscription callback, or in a middleware.   Then, as part of your app's setup process, retrieve the persisted state (from the server or `localStorage` or wherever you persisted it), and pass it as the second argument to `createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got `Uncaught TypeError: state.get is not a function`  while I'm doing this `store = Redux.createStore(indexReducer, restore_status, middleware);`.

Comment: Sounds like your logic is assuming use of Immutable.js Maps, but you're passing in plain JS data as the preloaded state.  If you're using Immutable.js, you'd need to properly convert any serialized data back into Immutable.js objects before inserting it into the state.  (This is one of the reasons why I generally recommend against using Immutable.js .)

Comment: Understood~ got it! thanks so much! your solution helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have used `window.localStorage` for this.

```
const MyReducer = (state,action) => {

    switch(action.type){
        ... 
        case 'SAVE_STATE':
            stateString = JSON.stringify(state.toJS())
            window.localStorage.setItem('applicationState', stateString)
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a reducer for that.  Either do it in `store.subscribe(callback)`, or use a middleware.

Comment: Hmmmm good idea, but that also depends on whether you want to only save the state sometimes or have it update on every dispatch.

Comment: Still shouldn't be done in a reducer :)  Reducers aren't supposed to have side effects, and and that _absolutely_ qualifies as a side effect.  The code will run, but it's not "right", and there's better places to do that work.  Middleware in particular would be the right way to handle that example.

Comment: Haha, a purist. You're definitely right. I would also consider this a small "cheat" to be able to `dispatch(saveState())` and `dispatch(loadState())` and have their functionality handled in consecutive lines of code, rather than loading state in a reducer (which I wouldn't say is a side effect) and having code elsewhere to save state. I was wondering why I got coal in my stocking last christmas..

Comment: Yes, I'm a purist - I'm a Redux maintainer :)  And seriously, a middleware is the right place to do this.  Middleware can respond to specific actions, so you'd still be able to dispatch "save" and "load" actions the way you described.